# How to save split text into excel file?

Tags: python, list, separator

I have an excel file containing a column of text with special characters such as the following:

```
Hi, My name is : Sam : and I live in : New York:
Hi, My name is : Samantha : and I live in : New Jersey:
Hi, My name is : John : and I live in : England:
Hi, My name is : Samuel : and I live in : India:
```

and i want to separate each rows of text by the separator colon separator ":" and this would give me two text one "Sam" and the other "New York". 
How do i save these two items in a separate excel file after separating each lines of rows?

First, i have tried to save the column into a list and use the for loop to go through each rows to separate the text on each rows. These has worked to separate each rows by the delimiter ":" however i am having problem saving the separated text

```
l = 0
for i in range(0,2):
    print(infolist[l].split(sep=':'))
    l+=1
```

Comment: what are you expecting `range(0,2)` to do?

Comment: And your file is saved as an `.xlsx` file? or something else Excel can read like a `.csv`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the initial code block saved as a `.csv` file you can do this pretty easily:

```
import csv

with open('test.csv', 'r') as file:
    my_reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=':')
    for row in my_reader:
        print(row)
```

Where you specify the ":" as a delimiter

Output:

```
['Hi, My name is ', ' Sam ', ' and I live in ', ' New York', '']
['Hi, My name is ', ' Samantha ', ' and I live in ', ' New Jersey', '']
['Hi, My name is ', ' John ', ' and I live in ', ' England', '']
['Hi, My name is ', ' Samuel ', ' and I live in ', ' India', '']
```

I believe it would work with other file extensions as well and you just need to change `'test.csv'` to your file name. Additionally `csv` comes standard with python so there is no need to `pip install` anything!

If this isn't what you were asking I think you need to rephrase your question and be more specific